# Help solving non-trivial logarithmic inequality

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I have the following equation:
$$\dfrac{2\pi G\lambda M^4}{m^2}\ln\left(\dfrac{\phi_i}{\phi_e}\right)+2\pi G\left(\phi_i^2-\phi_e^2\right)\ge 65$$

which, for the purpose of this question, I'll rewrite as:
$$\ln{x}+ax^2\ge b$$

with $a$ and $b$ constants, and $x>0$.

I'd gladly appreciate any help solving this equation. I have thought about using the Lambert W function, but I can't get around the difference of powers in $x$. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: Following `marty cohen`'s advice, I make the change of variable $y=x^2$ and get:
$$\ln y+2ay\ge 2b\Longleftrightarrow 2ay\cdot e^{2ay}\ge 2a\cdot e^{2b}\Longleftrightarrow 2ay\ge W(2a\cdot e^{2b})$$

and finally:
$$x\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{W(2a\cdot e^{2b})}{2a}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y = x^2$.
The inequality becomes
$\ln{y^{1/2}}+ay\ge b
$
or
$\ln y + 2ay \ge 2b
$
so that
Lambert can be used.

Comment: Would you mind having a look at my edit? Is my solution correct?

Comment: You mix together $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Typos, sorry. Fixed now.